How to handle a set of enums in SQLModel?
I have a table named Fruit in my SQLite database where I want to save a list of enum values:
class Colors(Enum):
    GREEN = "green"
    RED = "red"
    BLUE = "blue"
    YELLOW = "yellow"


class Fruit(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    colors: set[Colors]

This throws:

ValueError: <class 'set'> has no matching SQLAlchemy type

As expected, since SQLite does not support lists or sets as datatypes. How to save a set or list of enums for a particular field using SQLModel, and SQLite as databases, avoiding creating a many-to-many relationship table as described in the SQLModel docs?

Why don't you want to create a many-to-many relationship?

Coming from MongoDB, this seems a bit overkill, no?

And how would you name the column, if the table is named "Color", then there would be only a single field containing the actual value for the color. Is there a best practice or naming convention on how to name columns in tables that have just the single column?

what do you want the underlying type to be in your database?

on the underlying type in the database I do not have an opinion, it is important to me that i can access in python the the value of Fruit.colors easily as a set or list of colors, colors being of type enum Colors.

to somewhat answer the direct question, colors: set[Colors] = Field(sa_type=JSON) or replace JSON with whatever type you want from sqlalchemy import <your_type>, this should make that error go away, but you will run into JSON encoding issues etc which I am not familiar with in SQLModel, you are better of creating relationships

this indeed sounds error prone - do yo recommend using a many to many relationship table instead? Or what is the common practice for SQL/ SQLite?

yes, properly normalizing to a m2m table would be my suggestion as well, you can look into relationships and association proxy to make life easier in python land

thanks! In the SQLAlchemy example, it seems that the convention for names of columns in tables with just one column is, that table and column have the same name: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html
